# Check ArrayList elements contains some letter

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a `ArrayList<String>` which is already defined as :

```
[football,ballkeeping ,basket]
```

how can we check if every elements contain letter `p` or not? As much as i know if we want to check whole element then we use `.contains()` but here in this case what should be used?  So my desired output is `[ballkeeping]` as it contains letter `p`. Hope my question is clear.
Maybe pattern can help me but i am not able to figure out!

Comment: You would use a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
List<String> withP = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String s : myList) {
    if (s.contains("p") {
        withP.add(s);
    }
}
System.out.println("Words that contain P: " + withP);
```

Comment: The Concept was simple but i was foolish! Thanks a lot for the reminder.

Answer (score 3):

in Java 8 you could

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("football");
    list.add("ballkeeping");
    list.add("basket");
    System.out.println(
      list.
        stream().
        filter((s) -> s.contains("p")).
        collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you got many answers already showing how to use loops, I'll at least add one which doesn't, and uses the Java 8 features introduced to solve that kind of problems in a faster and more elegant way:

```
List<String> result = list.stream()
                          .filter(s -> s.indexOf('p') >= 0)
                          .collect(Collector.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your options too. It was informative and helpful for me.

Answer (score -1):

go through foreach and check each value separately. Code:

```
for(String value:yourList) {
    if (value.contains("p") {
        return value;
    }
}
```